# Lazy initialization exception

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I am getting error like this in spring annotations
and i was taking fetch type lazy
and retrieve data from database and return type is json data 
json is not working i am getting error like

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.gallileo.maintenance.customers.model.CustomerrModel.rates, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:411)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON.addInstance(AbstractJSON.java:63)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromCollection(JSONArray.java:1035)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:123)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:240)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2655)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2721)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2736)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1424)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.defaultBeanProcessing(JSONObject.java:765)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:699)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:172)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:274)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2655)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2721)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2736)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1424)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.defaultBeanProcessing(JSONObject.java:765)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:699)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:172)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:274)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._processValue(JSONArray.java:2513)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.processValue(JSONArray.java:2538)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.addValue(JSONArray.java:2525)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromCollection(JSONArray.java:1056)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:123)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:105)
    at com.gallileo.rates.clientrates.controller.ClientRatesController.ClientRatesRetrive1(ClientRatesController.java:368)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried researching your issue? Its a fairly standard problem that occurs because Hibernate can't load your `rates` collection because there is no Hibernate session. Either eagerly load the collection of `rates` or access them within a Hibernate transaction.

Comment: if i am taking fetch type eager then here occured one more excepton that is ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table. so i am taking fetch type lazy then getting previous error why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i got the answer just I add @transactional in my Action Controller exception was cleared